# Proportional Image Resizing

Tags: image-processing

This is quite a simple one I guess (but my mind is dead currently and is getting cluttered by other numbers).

I have an square image that is currently 256 width x 256 height.

I am variably resizing this image to a bigger size proportionally, so lets say I resize the image to 350 width to 350 height.

I then take a **seperate image** that is 416 width by 416 height and want to scale this to match the translation that was previously done in the last sentance. So I'm mirroring whats going on...

How would I calculate the 416x416's final size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first image has changed from $256$ to $350$, a $350/256$ change.

The second image should change by the same factor: from $416$ to $416 \cdot 350/256 = 568.75$. So choose $568$ or $569$ as the final size.

Comment: Perfect thank you. The carification helped! Looks like something else was at play in my problem.